# Access get_the_title() from 'excerpt_length' filter

Tags: filters, excerpt, get-the-title

Is there a way to access the `get_the_title()` function from a `excerpt_length` filter?

For example, setting the excerpt length to be the same as the title:

```
function excerpt_length_same_as_title( $length ) {
        $title_len = strlen(get_the_title());
        return $title_len;
    }
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'excerpt_length_same_as_title', 999 );
```

Comment: I can think of several potential solutions/problems, but off the top of my head, why don't you just trim the excerpt in the loop to match the title? Sorry, I don't have a lot of time atm, I will check back later.

Answer (score 0):

Allow me to purpose an alternative. Instead of setting the excerpt's length for all the posts, let's just trim it for individual posts. Shall we?

For this very purpose, we can use [`get_the_excerpt`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/get_the_excerpt) filter. If you look at the corresponding page about this filter, you notice that the code example is using `is_attachment()`, which means you have access to the global `$wp_query`.

We hook into the `get_the_excerpt` filter, and use a custom function to trim the excerpt:

```
add_filter( 'get_the_excerpt', 'custom_excerpt_more' );
function custom_excerpt_more( $excerpt ) {
    // Get the current post
    $post = get_post();
    // Calculate the length of its title
    $charlength = strlen( $post->post_title );
    $charlength++;
    if ( mb_strlen( $excerpt ) > $charlength ) {
        $subex = mb_substr( $excerpt, 0, $charlength - 5 );
        $exwords = explode( ' ', $subex );
        $excut = - ( mb_strlen( $exwords[ count( $exwords ) - 1 ] ) );
        if ( $excut < 0 ) {
            $output = mb_substr( $subex, 0, $excut );
        } else {
            $output = $subex;
        }
        $output .= ' ...';
        return $output;
    } else {
        return $excerpt;
    }
}
```

There you go. Your excerpt is now trimmed by its post title.